# Which Super Mario Galaxy 2 challenge requires the player to activate four switches in 10 seconds?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

I recall a challenge in Super Mario Galaxy where you had around 10 seconds to activate 4 switches (Level Switches I guess they would have been). It was a square/rectangular area and you had to go to the four corners and shake the remote. It was extremely hard. It was like Gearmo's challenges to blow up or incinerate the trash.

It's not from SMG1 (I just finished replaying the game). I'm playing SMG2 now but I looked at all the levels online and don't see anything like what I'm describing. Does this level/challenge sound familiar to anyone? I don't think I dreamt this up, but you never know...

Comment: It's definitely not the right forum, because it's not a forum. ;) Anyway, hitting a bunch of switches is a common element in many SMG2 levels. Time restrictions are also a common element, but there is never an explicit on-screen countdown that starts at 10 seconds.

Comment: It was just like the Gearmo challenges but I looked those up and didn't see anything like what I'm describing. The timer could have been 12s or maybe 15s but not more. Perhaps it is another 3D Super Mario game? I only own a Wii and the only two Super Mario games I own are SMG1 and SMG2. I rented a game once before buying these, but I believe it was SMG1.